# VB.NET to ACCESS DataBase, Data not being saved

Tags: ms-access, vb.net-2010

I am having trouble with my Data Save routine, saving data from several textbox's into an MSACCESS database. The code throws no errors, completes successful, but the database is not accessed. I assume it is the connection that is causing the problem but cannot see why. Can anyone suggest where I am going wrong?     Thank you for looking.

```
 cn = New OleDbConnection
    cn.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & databaseName & "; Persist Security Info=False;"
    Dim cmd As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand()
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text

    cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE [BRLocoDatabase2] SET [aDate] = @aDate, [aDepot] = @aDepot, [bDate] = @bDate, [bDepot] = @bDepot," & _
        " [cDate] = @cDate, [cDepot] = @cDepot, [dDate] = @dDate, [dDepot] = @dDepot WHERE [LOCO] = @Loco"
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Loco", TextBox1.Text)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@aDate", TextBox19.Text)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@aDepot", TextBox20.Text)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@bDate", TextBox21.Text)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@bDepot", TextBox22.Text)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cDate", TextBox23.Text)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cDepot", TextBox24.Text)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dDate", TextBox25.Text)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dDepot", TextBox26.Text)

    cmd.Connection = cn
    cn.Open()
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    MessageBox.Show("Update was a Success!")
    cn.Close()
```

...

Answer (score 1):

You are using OLEDB and OLEDB doesn't support named arguments. Your ability to use named parameters is just a syntactic sugar. Still those parameters are used by position. In your code, you have xDate which is likely dates, then xDepot and finally a where criteria Loco. But in your parameters you are adding Loco first and dDepot last. That would be interpreted like:

```
update .... set aDate = TextBox1.Text, ... where [Loco] = TextBox26.Text
```

Try changing your code to:

```
    dim sql as String = <sql>UPDATE [BRLocoDatabase2] 
         SET [aDate] = @aDate, [aDepot] = @aDepot, 
             [bDate] = @bDate, [bDepot] = @bDepot,
             [cDate] = @cDate, [cDepot] = @cDepot, 
             [dDate] = @dDate, [dDepot] = @dDepot 
         WHERE [LOCO] = @Loco</sql>
    using cn as OleDbConnection = New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & databaseName & "; Persist Security Info=False;")
    using cmd As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand(sql, cn)

    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@aDate", TextBox19.Text)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@aDepot", TextBox20.Text)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@bDate", TextBox21.Text)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@bDepot", TextBox22.Text)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cDate", TextBox23.Text)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cDepot", TextBox24.Text)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dDate", TextBox25.Text)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dDepot", TextBox26.Text)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Loco", TextBox1.Text)

    cn.Open()
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    MessageBox.Show("Update was a Success!")
    cn.Close()
    end using
end using
```

EDIT: BTW, instead of AddWithValue, try using Add, specify the corret types and convert those textBoxN.Text to corresponding types (ie: DateTime.TryParse for xDate values).

Comment: Thank you to both contributors.  I now have a working solution. I incorporated the ideas you have both selected, and changed the code slightly to use the record ID, rather than the fieldname 'LOCO', which is the more logical thing to do. The data is now saved into the correct locations within the database, so all is Now O.K.     Again let me thank you both for your assistance and knowledge.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, first, you probably really, but really want to put your connection string into some global settings to the project.
Not only will this save you having to re-type the connection ALL OVER the place in code, but you can also test the connection, and ensure it is valid.

So, project->"choose my project Properties.

Then settings:

[image]

So, now we get to use the connection builder.
(click on the [...])

Now:

[image]

then

[image]

Now, you can browse to the accDB (or mdb).

This:

And do NOT skip hitting advanced:

[image]

Then choose ACE (for accDB) or JET (for mdb)

this:

[image]

Now, if you are using vs2022, since it is now the FIRST version of VS to be x64 bits, then the test connection will NOT work (unless you using x64 Access/office).

But, at least now we have a connection string. If you using a pre-vs2022 version then test connection WILL work. As a additional step, you should set/force the project to x86.

Eg this:
[image]

DO NOT use "any cpu". You need/want/better force the project to x86 (x32 bits) if you using Access/ACE/Office x32.

On the other hand, if you using Access/ACE/Office x64, then of course you set/force the project to x64 bits.

Next up:

While you CAN USE named parameters with ACE and the oleDB provider?

The ORDER must be correct!! (only the position matters)

While I STILL suggest you use named parameters (since in the future, you can flip to SQL server or other oleDB providers, and THEY DO SUPPORT named providers.

So, keep in mind that you can use named parameters, but ONLY the order is what matters.

Another FYI:

Don't use addwith - use STRONG data typing.

So, this code should work:

```
    Using conn As New OleDbConnection(My.Settings.TEST444)
        Dim strSQL As String =
            "UPDATE [BRLocoDatabase2] SET [aDate] = @aDate, [aDepot] = @aDepot, [bDate] = @bDate,
                    [bDepot] = @bDepot, [cDate] = @cDate, [cDepot] = @cDepot,
                    [dDate] = @dDate, [dDepot] = @dDepot WHERE [LOCO] = @Loco"

        Using cmd As New OleDbCommand(strSQL, conn)

            With cmd.Parameters
                .Add("@aDate", OleDbType.Date).Value = TextBox19.Text
                .Add("@aDepot", OleDbType.VarWChar).Value = TextBox20.Text
                .Add("@bDate", OleDbType.Date).Value = TextBox21.Text
                .Add("@bDepot", OleDbType.VarWChar).Value =  TextBox22.Text
                .Add("@cDate", OleDbType.Date).Value = TextBox23.Text
                .Add("@dDepot", OleDbType.VarWChar).Value = TextBox26.Text
                .Add("@dDate", OleDbType.Date).Value = TextBox25.Text
                .Add("@cDepot", OleDbType.VarWChar).Value = TextBox24.Text
                .Add("@Loco", OleDbType.Integer).Value = TextBox1.Text
            End With
            conn.Open()
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
            MessageBox.Show("Update was a Success!")
        End Using
    End Using
```

Comment: Thanks for replies...Changed code to that suggested, changed Parameters accordingly as all are strings. Changed connection string as suggested, OK but only Providor options I had were Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0 and Microsoft.Ace.OLEDB.12.0  Tried both and had same error each time,  OLEDB Exception.."Command text was not set for the command object"  Tested connection for aach providor and both were O.K.

Comment: well, posted code was this ---- Using cmd As New OleDbCommand("", conn) --- should have been ---  Using cmd As New OleDbCommand(strSQL, conn) ---   so give that a try. As noted, you want to select ACE if using a accDB file. Also as noted, you need to force your project to x86. And as noted, if using vs2022, the test connection will ALWAYS fail unless you using x64 bit access/ACE. While test connection will fail, when you run the code, it should work (assuming  you using vs2022). If using previous version, then test connection will work (for ACE x32), but fail for x64 (so the reverse!!)

Comment: So I made a edit to the code - my error my bad.

Comment: @DaveUU, did you really try the code I provided at all? As I said, your error is in the order of parameters not the connection string.

Comment: @DaveUU, and BTW install both 32 and 64 bits drivers and you would be fine.

Comment: Cetin.. Yes I have tried your code and I do now realise the ordering of the parameters is important. The code says it has worked OK, but in relaity the Database has not been edited.

Comment: Thanks Albert for update. Changed code and now runs O.K., but as in my reply to Cetin, the dataBase itself still has not been edited.  To Both....... I Have checked the tablename OK, have checked the databasename is the full and correct path OK, have checked the field names, O.K. so I am back to my original issue.

Comment: I would debug print or messagebox the value of loco to see what value. So exit access if open. Run your code and then open access and look at table. In fact while access is open, can you edit the row ok? So check if loco id exists in table. If I'd don't exist then no update will occur (suggests you need a insert for such cases - update only works if row already exists)

Comment: Thanks again for update. Will try in morning again, although have tried most whilst trying to solve issue. Thanks.

Comment: @DaveUU are you sure that the value you are looking for exists? Did you try the same update (hardcoding values temporarily) from within access itself? Best would be not to use access if possible. It is guaranteed to pose a problem sooner or later anyway.